Powershell Job does not fail as expected
i ran into a strange situation which i can not explain to myself.
I have solved it by a workaround, so got my result, but i would like to understand why my workaround is needed.
 $scr = {
     $someVar = ""
     nonsenseCmd
 }

If i start this as a Job like this :
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scr | Wait-Job | Get-Job

my expectation is that the job will fail, due to the nonsenseCmd.
But the result is Completedinstead of Failed.

Now, if i comment the very first line of the scriptblock :
$scr = {
    #$someVar = ""
    nonsenseCmd
}

the job fails as i have excpected it :

Receive-Job 19


The way i solved this for me now is to use Exceptions.
$scr = {
    try {
         $someVar = ""
         nonsenseCmd
     } catch {
         Write-Host $_
         throw
     }
 }



So is using try/catch realy needed in this situation?
Why does the job as shown in the first example does not fail?
I have tested it with

and

Regards
Ronny from Germany

The behavior is the expected one because default action preference is Continue. If you put $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' on top of your Job scriptblock then it will be Failed.

It's a little odd that there's a difference.  Start-ThreadJob says completed in both cases. The exception doesn't stop the script.

Start-ThreadJob is only availible in PS7, which unfortunatly is not availible at the productive system, so i need to run my script in PS5...

You can install the Threadjob module in powershell 5.
